# What is the difference between ftime() and time() C++

Tags: c++, time

Can anyone explain if there is a difference between `ftime()` and `time()`?

Comment: @AlokSave: That's an answer, not a comment. :-)

Comment: It seems, that `ftime` is Microsoft specific... I could not find an information about ftime neihter at cpluscplus.com nor at cppreference.com

Comment: @borisbn: POSIX, not Microsoft.

Comment: It is POSIX and Microsoft specific, but not standard, see latest info about its implemetation from Microsoft: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/18/crt-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ftime()` is a (deprecated) POSIX function to get both seconds and miliseconds since epoch, `time()` is ISO C (and, thanks to that, ISO C++ as well) function to get seconds since epoch.

Quoting from [`ftime(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/ftime.3.html) man page:

> This function is obsolete.  Don't use it.  If the time in seconds suffices, time(2) can be used; gettimeofday(2) gives microseconds; clock_gettime(2) gives nanoseconds but is not as widely available.

Since you are writing C++, consider using [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) from C++11, which is native way to work with time intervals in C++.